# How does our iPhone app use the public API?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've been struggling with this for a while and hope someone can help. We have a Rails API, it's currently private on AWS. There is an Angular App frontend and iPhone App which consume the API. That's fine.

We now want to open up the API to the public using token based authentication (not oauth as it will be for the single user and not need other account data). So a user generates a token within their profile area and makes requests using that token in a header. How does the iPhone App and Angular App bypass this? as the controllers will need the token to authenticate? but the iPhone and web app won't know what the users generated token is. Also the token may only be available for some users.

Or is it a case of logging a user in through a form and bypassing the authentication through these devices. Sorry I just cannot get my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the ROR controllers.  These can be empty except for a before filter that requires an api token.  Give these their own subdirectory and their own routes, like 'myApp/api/subclassedController'.  Now your internal apps and public api share the same code except for the authorization.